# How do you block someone's "shared" and "Likes" from your newsfeed?

Tags: facebook, sharing

I have friends who have a tendency to ABUSE the share button.  I don't want to see the stuff they share, but I want to see everything else.

How can I do this, or is this something I can't change?

Comment: Maybe some people are too stupid to have as friends (as least on facebook)…

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you can block only shares and likes.

What you can do, though, is clicking the downward arrow on a post by one of those users, and selecting "Only important" from the "Subscribed to X" section.

True, you will see very few of the things they post (*guess what? Only the **important** ones!*), but odds are good that if they constantly share dumb crap, they won't post anything worthwhile of their own either.

Comment: I have always been curious as to what criteria is used to distinguish a post as being "important". I assume (wild guess here) it has to do with the cumulated "likes".I have used this setting in the past with more or less success.

Answer (score 2):

You can change what types of stories get posted to your newsfeed.

When a friend posts something, you can:

- Hover over their name to get their hover card profile
- Hover over "Friends" (might be titled something else depending on what friend list they are organized
- Click on "Settings"

The resulting menu will not only allow you to select "Only Important" stories like @sm's answer states, but it will also allow you to choose what **types** of stories appear from your friend.

[image]

In your case you might try unselecting "Comments and Likes" and "Other activity," but I suggest fiddling with the different types of stories and seeing which selections best serve your preferences.